# Submit button does not go to other page

Tags: php, authentication

I got a problem with my login page.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include("include/config.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['captcha_code']) && isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    
    if ($_SESSION['captcha_code'] == $_POST['captcha']) {
    $ret=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."' and password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
    $num=mysqli_fetch_array($ret);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($ret) > 0) {
    
        
        echo "<script>alert('Successfully Registered. You can login now');
         window.location.href ='dashboard.php';</script>";
    }
    } else {
        // CAPTCHA code is incorrect, show an error message and allow the user to try again
        $_SESSION['errmsg']="Invalid email, password or CAPTCHA code";
        $extra="user-login.php";
        $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uri  = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/\\');
        header("location:http://$host$uri/$extra");
    }
    
        exit();
      
    
    }

?>

<html>
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="input-icon">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-actions">
    <span class="input-icon">
    <input type="password" class="form-control password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
    </span><a href="forgot-password.php">
    Forgot Password ?
    </a>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
    <div class="form-group form-actions">
    <img src="captcha.php" alt="Captcha Code" id="captchaImg">
    <a href="javasript: void(0);" onclick="refreshCaptcha();"><i class="fa fa-fresh"></i></a>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" id = "captcha_code" placeholder="Enter above captcha">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="submit">Login <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
    </button>
</div>
</html>
```

This page from my login.php. When the user clicks the submit button, the user is supposed to go to dashboard.php. In my case, it only generated a script alert but stayed on the login page. This happens when users insert a valid email, password, and captcha. I hope I can get a solution for this code. Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: I don't see a `form` element. What do you expect the `button` to submit, if it's not inside a `form`?

Comment: What is the output of: `http://$host$uri/$extra`?

Comment: I do not copy the whole code here, but I have a `form` element in my code  @bassxzero

Comment: `$extra="user-login.php";` I got this from the internet. @SachinBahukhandi

Comment: What is the output of `http://$host$uri/$extra`? I want to see what exactly is the output of the statement?

Comment: This should stay on the login page and the error message appears. But when I purposely enter the wrong password or email, it will show blank page of login page